# php in_array() inside a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having issues with using in_array() inside a foreach loop. Not sure if this is even possible or if I am doing something ridiculous where there are better ways. What I want to do is go through all the items and if their item id matches one thats in the array, return true and add the price of the item to a runninng total.

```
$price = 0;
$result = false;
$array = array(1533, 2343, 2333);

foreach($order['items'] as $item){
  if(in_array($item['Item'], $array)){
     $result = true;
     $price += $item['Price'];
  }
}

**UPDATED**
Here is the order array

[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Item] => 139957
                [OrderID] => 16025
                [SizeID] => 24
                [Price] => 46.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Item] => 2343
                [OrderID] => 16025
                [SizeID] => 12
                [Price] => 32.00
            )
    )

[data] => Array
    (
    )
```

Comment: Ccheck your usage of array on line 3 shown. Should be `$array = array(....);` and what is the primary array you are comparing to.. What does that look like?

Comment: Please show your definition of `$order`.

Comment: The code looks okay, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: I can't get it to return true, maybe I got something simple messing with it

Comment: a function will 'return' for you. This will return nothing, you will need to check for the value of $result after the loop to see if it was true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$price = 0;
$result = false;
$array = array(1533, 2343, 2333);

foreach($order['items'] as $item){
  if(in_array($item['Item'], $array)){
     $result = true;
     $price += $item['Price'];
  }
}

if ($result)
{
    echo 'was true';
}
else
{
    echo 'was false';
}
```

Technically you don't even need the $result variable since if $price is more than 0 then of course it was true, unless the price of item was free ($0).

Comment: Thanks for the help, this got it working and was able to move onto pulling the string from the db.